# How to set a localStorage in ReactJS correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm using CodePen for a ReactJS project.
I need to set the `localStorage` for a part of the state that is:

```js
this.state={
    Things:{
        element:"value",
        element2: "value"
    },
    activated:-1
}
```

Since I need to set only `Things` I decided to set the `localStorage` in the component lifecycle: `componentDidUpdate()`

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
    localStorage.setItem("myThings",JSON.stringify(this.state.Things));
}
```

Here if I call  `console.log(localStorage.getItem("myThings"))` I don't get any stored value.

For the `localStorage` checking part I implemented a solution in the constructor because I read in the React documentation that one should prefer the constructor to the `componentWillMount()` method (although I tried the latter too).

```js
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if (localStorage.getItem("myThings")!==null){
        this.state={
            Things:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myThings")),
            activated:-1
        }
     }
     ...
```

Comment: The typo was only on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error from distraction. The problem was the missing `else` in the constructor after the `if(...){...}` statement. so it was setting every time the next state after the state set in the if statement.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

setItem is a function:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
    localStorage.setItem("myThings",JSON.stringify(this.state.Things));
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if you need to store more complex data structures, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010994/2549154

Answer (score 0):

As stated from above setItem is a function. You may also need to access localStorage on the window obj.

```
window.localStorage.setItem(...);
```

or make a variable for it and reference that for a shorthand.

```
const storage = window.localStorage;
storage.setItem(...);
```